# SubSet sum with N array Solution, Dynamic Solution recquired

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Though you can have any number of `array`s but let's Suppose you have two `array`s {1,2,3,4,5,6} and {1,2,3,4,5,6}
You have to find whether they sum upto 4 with participation of both `array` elements. i.e.

```
1 from array1, 3 from array2
2 from array1, 2 from array2
3 from array1, 1 from array2
```

etc

**In Nutshell:Want to implement SubSet Sum Algorithm where there is two arrays and array elements are chosen from both of the arrays to make up the target Sum**

here is the **subset sum algorithm** that I use for one `array`

```
bool subset_sum(int a[],int n, int sum)
{
 bool dp[n+1][sum+1];


   int i,j;

   for(i=0;i<=n;i++)   
      dp[i][0]=true;

   for(j=1;j<=sum;j++)
        dp[0][j]=false;

   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)

    {

        for(j=1;j<=sum;j++)

       {

           if(dp[i-1][j]==true)

              dp[i][j]=true;

           else
           {

               if(a[i-1]>j)

                   dp[i][j]=false;

                else

                    dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j-a[i-1]];

            }

        }

    }
  return dp[n][sum];
}
```

Comment: Is participation from **all** the arrays is a must?

Comment: Initial "Dice Throw" formulation was more clear.

Comment: Yes participation both array mandatory

Comment: -MBo I thought it would be confusing though

Comment: @Andrew Watson  Now it looks like completely different problem. And unclear. You'd better to show real problem.

Comment: -MBo  No the problem is same. Actually I want to implement subset sum algorithm with two array. thtats all.

Comment: @AndrewWatson, can participation from some arrays be greater than one element?

Comment: Actually the given sum will be in such a way that is both array will participate equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can implement this with a 3 dimensional dp. But for simplicity and readability I have written it using two methods.

**NOTE** : My solution works when we choose **at least one element** from each `array`. It doesn't work if there is a condition that we have to choose equal number of elements from each `array`.

```
// This is a helper method

//  prevPosAr[] is the denotes what values could be made with participation from ALL
// arrays BEFORE the current array

// This method returns an array which denotes what values could be made with the
// with participation from ALL arrays UP TO current array


boolean[] getPossibleAr( boolean prevPossibleAr[], int ar[] )
{
    boolean dp[][] = new boolean[ ar.length + 1 ][ prevPossibleAr.length  ];
    // dp[i][j] denotes   if we can make value j using AT LEAST
    // ONE element from current ar[0...i-1]

    for (int i = 1; i <= ar.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dp[i].length; j++)
        {
            if ( dp[i-1][j] == true )
            {
                // we can make value j using AT LEAST one element from ar[0...i-2]
                // it implies that we can also make value j using AT LEAST
                // one element from ar[0...i-1]
                dp[i][j] = true;
                continue;
            }

            int prev = i-ar[i-1];
            // now we look behind


            if ( prev < 0 )
            {
                // it implies that ar[i-1] > i
                continue;
            }

            if ( prevPossibleAr[prev] || dp[i-1][prev] )
            {
                // It is the main catch
                // Be careful


                // if ( prevPossibleAr[prev] == true )
                // it means that we could make the value prev
                // using the previous arrays (without using any element
                // of the current array)
                // so now we can add ar[i-1] with prev and eventually make i



                // if ( dp[i-1][prev] == true )
                // it means that we could make prev using one or more
                // elements from the current array....
                // now we can add ar[i-1] with this and eventually make i

                dp[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // What is dp[ar.length] ?
    // It is an array of booleans
    // It denotes whether we can make value j using ALL the arrays 
    // (using means taking AT LEAST ONE ELEMENT)
    // before the current array and using at least ONE element 
    // from the current array ar[0...ar.lengh-1] (That is the full current array)

    return dp[ar.length];
}



// This is the method which will give us the output
boolean subsetSum(int  ar[][], int sum )
{
    boolean prevPossible[] = new boolean[sum+1];
    prevPossible[0] = true;


    for ( int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++ )
    {
        boolean newPossible[] = getPossibleAr(prevPossible, ar[i]); 
        // calling that helper function
        // newPossible denotes what values can be made with
        // participation from ALL arrays UP TO i th array
        // (0 based index here)



        prevPossible = newPossible;
    }

    return prevPossible[sum];
}
```

Comment: Highly appreciate your hard work and voted up.Can you please comment out what you have done inside the for loop?

Comment: @AndrewWatson, There are several `for` loops in my solution. Could you point out which for loop you would like to get comment?

Comment: Thanks for paying attention.Inside the getPossibleAr function.

Comment: @AndrewWatson,  I have added more comments in that area. Plz let me know if you have any problem to understand.

Comment: @AndrewWatson, My pleasure. I enjoyed answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Steps,

```
find (Array1, Array2, N)
  sort Array1
  sort Array2

  for (i -> 0 && i < Array1.length) and (j -> Array2.length-1 && j >= 0)
    if(Array1[i] + Array2[j] == N)
      return yes;
    if(Array1[i] + Array2[j] > N)
      j--;
    else
      i++;
  return NO;
```

Comment: it's not dynamic solution and limited only with two arrays.Please provide a dynamic solution

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic solution? whats your expected complexity? please mention in the question clearly if you want to use more than two array.

Comment: Actually I want to implement subset sum algorithm where  there is two arrays and  elements are chosen from two different arrays. I've provided my code that use to implement subset sum algorithm where there is only on array.